# Allowing access for multiple users on one page

Tags: php, session, restrict

Ok, I'm only learning php as we speak. I have staff area and admin area. I need to allow admin into the staff area via sessions.

My sessions restricting access only for user_level of 1 (staff)

```
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_level']) OR ($_SESSION['user_level'] != 1){
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
        }
```

I.m trying to allow admin to access these pages as well as staff.

session_start();

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_level']) OR ($_SESSION['user_level'] != 1) OR ($_SESSION['user_level'] != 2))
        {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
        }
```

This is not allowing my admins to access the staff pages. How can i allow user_level 1 and user_level 2 access to the same pages?
I have them both sorted on the log-in page. When i log-in as admin i go to admin area when i log-in as staff i go to staff area. But when i log-in as admin, and try in the menu to get to the staff pages i can not gain access.

Comment: you could do some simple if operations.... 

if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1 || $_SESSION['user_level'] == 2) { echo 'user page'; }

Comment: how do i show you as the answer for my question? Your answer worked so thank you

Comment: its ok. glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your user levels and permissions follow a incremental order you could just use greater than.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_level']) || ($_SESSION['user_level'] > 2)){
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit();
}
```

I would also use || instead of OR, but that's just personal preference!

If that still doesn't work than I would put a breakpoint in or remove the header and

```
echo($_SESSION['user_level'])
```

to see what it is.